# Adobe Reader read loud in not working on my Linux

Tags: adobe-reader

The "**read out loud**" feature will not work on my **Adobe Reader 9**. It *loads,* and acts as if it should work, but I cannot hear anything. There are *NO issues* with my computer's audio.

On my preferences >>>the Read Loud option is not accesable

---

Does anyone have a **fix for this** ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a few months ago...

So i followed the steps described [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=884168).

Short version:

1. Go to the synaptic package manager
2. Mark the Adobe Acrobat Reader for complete removal
3. Mark "Acroread" for installation
4. Perfom the marked changes
5. Restart Adobe Acrobat Reader

For me it worked. Hopefully for you too...

Comment: thank for reply  PRR3 but not working any other tips